# InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic> when try to parse JSON

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I learn flutter through the step-by-step guide. So, when I use code from the guide - it's working good, but when I try to change JSON URL, I get the error. As I understand, the problem with JSON format and jsonDecode just can't decode RIOT JSON, but how to fix it?

```
List _games = await getGames();

Future<List> getGames() async {


    //Not working with this JSON URL
    String apiUrl = 'https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/UZs5l9TT7GLEPfoOZ1eTMqqyJEomgmUHueGQ2aFNHaYTOZI/?api_key=RGAPI-07972f29-94f8-4d54-a2dd-527d4eeb0335';

    //Working good with this JSON URL
    String apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
  print(jsonDecode(response.body));
  return jsonDecode(response.body);
}
```

Comment: Hiya! Welcome to Stack Overflow. What error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Future<List>
```

to

```
Future<Map<String,dynamic>>
```

If you have JSON like `[1, 2, 3]` or `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` you get a `List`, but if you have JSON like `{"foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3}` you get a `Map<String,dynamic>`. For `"foo"` you'd get a `String` and for `true` a `bool`, and so forth. I guess you get the idea.